# ARM assembly : Access array elements residing in C type struct

Tags: c, arrays, assembly, arm, neon

I have a ARM Neon function that uses C type struct as the argument. 
I have a `float*` and `float[]` array of fixed size in that struct. I am able to access `float*` elements in my assembly function. But when I try to access elements of array, my program crashes.

Here is my C side application:

```
typedef struct{
float*  f1;
float*  f2;
float   f3[4];
}P_STRUCT;
```

main.c file:

```
extern void myNeonFunc(P_STRUCT*    p, float* res);
P_STRUCT p;
// memory allocation for f1,f2 and fill array f3 here.
// memory allocation for res

myNeonFunc(&p, res);
```

And here is my .S file:

```
.text

.set    P_STRUCT_F1,        0                   @ float* f1
.set    P_STRUCT_F2,        4                   @ float* f2
.set    P_STRUCT_F3,        8                   @ float f3[4]

.globl myNeonFunc

@ void myNeonFunc   (P_STRUCT* p ---->  r0, r1 )

.balign     64                              @ align the function to 64

myNeonFunc:
@save callee-save registers here

ldr         r8,         [r0,P_STRUCT_F1]    @ r8 <- f1 
add         r8,    r8,  #8                  @ r8 points to the f1[2] (2*4 = 8 )
ldr         r9,         [r0,P_STRUCT_F2]    @ r9 <- f2
add         r9,    r9,  #4                  @ r9 points to the f2[1] (1*4 = 8)
ldr         r10,        [r0,P_STRUCT_F3]    @ r10 <- f3
add         r10,   r10, #4                  @ r10 points to the f3[1] (1*4 = 8)

vld1.f32    {d4},       [r8]!               @ d4 now contains the corresponding r8 value
vld1.f32    {d6},       [r9]!               @ d6 now contains the corresponding r9 value
vst1.32     {d4},       [r1]!               @ store f1[2] value in result register
vst1.32     {d6},       [r1]!               @ store f1[1] value in result register

// every thing is ok up to here
// this line probably causes seg fault !!!
vld1.f32    {d8},       [r10]!              @ d8 now contains the corresponding r10 value

//           
vst1.32     {d8},       [r1]!               @ store f3[1] value in result register

// epilog part here ...
```

This problem might be due to the fact that `r10` does not point to the address of `f3` array.(maybe)

Now my question is that why accessing fixed size array causes problem here while accessing pointer elements is OK. And what is the solution for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pointer is not the same thing as an array. `f1` and `f2` are 4 byte pointers in the struct.  `f3` is a 16-byte array in the struct.  The struct as a whole is 24 bytes long.

What you are loading into `r10` is the first element of `f3`.  If you want to set `r10`  to `&f3[0]`, then just set `r10` to `r0` + `P_STRUCT_F3`.